# Adding time stamp to current codebase revision

Tags: feature-request, timestamps, tooltips, footer

I am used to see full time stamps everywhere, when hovering a date. Questions, answers, bounty awards, virtually everything.

On each site we have the current code base revision on the bottom:

[image]

Is it possible to add tooltip showing the exact time when the revision was rolled out on that site?

Comment: 6-8 weeks ago ;)...